# Can't add resource file to xamarin android project in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, localization, resx, visual-studio-mac

Trying to add resx-files to my cross platform project. I was starting to look at the links for the toolkit but that seems to work only for VS for windows and I'm running Visual Studio of Mac on a... ...well, mac. Thought I wouldn't let that stop me and proceeded adding the resx-file manually and started with my Android project.

I've created a separate PCL project where I'd add my resource files. Creating the first AppResources.resx works fine and adding terms to that file updates the designer file accordingly, so far so good. However, when I try to add a second language and name the file according to examples I've seen online such as AppResources.it.resx I get an exception in the UI stating that the "File ..../Resources/AppResources.resx already exists.".

I'm hoping to use the same approach for my ios project so the solution should not limit that application.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you are using the New File dialog, then I believe this is a bug. The New File dialog does not support filenames that have two dot characters. It wants to take the first part of the name and then apply the default file extension for the file template to the created file. I would create a resx file with different filename, maybe just copy the existing AppResources.resx file outside the IDE, then rename it outside the IDE, and then add that file back to the project.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing as you said. Copy the default-resx file outside VS for Mac, edit the file name to add the ".it." and then drag it from finder into VS for Mac. Then the build action need to be changed from None to EmbeddedResource and the finally in my case as i have the resx'es in a separate PCL project, you need to change the property "Custom Tool" from "ResXFileCodeGenerator" to "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" to build the designer as public rather than internal (right click the file, select properties and edit the value). Now it all works!